# Named breaks in for loops in Rust

Tags: for-loop, break, rust

Is there a way to have nested `for` loops in Rust and break the outer one from inside the inner one, the way one could do e.g. in Java? I know Rust supports named breaks in `loop` but I can't seem to find information about the same regarding `for`.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Yes. It uses the same syntax as lifetimes.

```
fn main() {
    'outer: for x in 0..5 {
        'inner: for y in 0..5 {
            println!("{},{}", x, y);
            if y == 3 {
                break 'outer;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See [loop labels documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/first-edition/loops.html#loop-labels) and the related section of [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/loop-expr.html#loop-labels).

Comment: @NoeticJun It's mentioned in the section [Infinite loops](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.9/rust.html#infinite-loops) (followed by Break expressions). Although it's a bit confusing, because the example break is `break foo` instead of `break 'foo`. It also uses both "label" and "lifetime" to refer to the same thing. It should be rewritten.